# Entity Framework - DbUpdateException when adding entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net

I am trying to add a record into table using Entity Framework and I get `DbUpdateException` when I execute this method on `_entities.SaveChanges();` :

```
public Player CreatePlayer(int fideNumber, string name, string surname, DateTime birthDate, double? rating = null)
{
    var player = _entities.Players.Add(new Player
    {
        Id = fideNumber,
        BirthDate = new DateTime(birthDate.Year, birthDate.Month, birthDate.Day),
        Name = name,
        Surname = surname,
        Rating = 1500
    });

    _entities.SaveChanges();
    return player;
}
```

My `Player` model looks like this:

```
public partial class Player
{
    public Player()
    {
        this.Tournaments = new HashSet<Tournament>();
        this.GamesAsWhite = new HashSet<Game>();
        this.GamesAsBlack = new HashSet<Game>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Rating { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tournament> Tournaments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Game> GamesAsWhite { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Game> GamesAsBlack { get; set; }
}
```

I have created model via designer first and then generated my database. Tournament creation in this way works fine, but for some reason player creation throws an error. The type of field `Id` is `Computed`.

Comment: Since your `Id` field is computed (probably Identity), you should not assign a value to it.

Comment: For some reason, when I set my field to Identity the value would be generated automatically, but when I set my field to Identity, the value would be required...

Comment: OK, setting the Id field StoreGeneratedPattern to none solved the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "the value would be required"?

Comment: Yes, If you need to set the value of `Id` yourself, you should not use `Identity` for the column and you should set `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `none`.

Comment: Since the post answers the question, It would be great if you kindly accept and vote for the post. This way it will be more useful for future readers :) Its not compulsory at all, but is reasonable and recommended and your kindness :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Id field is `Identity`, you should not assign a value to it. SQL Server will assign a new `Identity` value to it.

Remove the line `Id = fideNumber`

Also If you need to set the value of `Id` yourself, you should not use `Identity` for the column and you should set `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `none`.